# Does adding a standard account to sudoers file defeat the purpose of standard account?

Tags: permissions, sudo

In order to avoid elevating privileges to the admin account every time I have to type in a sudo command (occasionally) I was thinking of adding the standard account that I use for everyday activity to the sudoers file, but does that defeat entirely the purpose of a separate daily standard user account, in terms of security?

BR

Comment: I see two ways to read this question: 1) "I want my user account to operate exactly like the admin account" or 2) "I want to use sudo without typing the admin password anymore." It's unclear which you mean, or if you perhaps mean something else.